# SQL: How to get all common values of a column group by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD6X7.png)

Now, I want to get all **Id**s from the **Session** table, where **Name** in **Users** is 'Bob'.
Then, after getting all **Id**s, I want to get common **Title**s for all these **SessionId**s.

I tried the following query:

```
WITH session as (SELECT "Id"
                  FROM "Sessions"
                  "UserId" = (SELECT "Id"
                              FROM "Users"
                              WHERE "UserName" = 'Bob')),
consts as (SELECT "SessionId"
           FROM "Consts")

SELECT "Title"
FROM "Consts"
WHERE "SessionId"
IN (SELECT "Id"
    FROM consts
    JOIN session
    ON consts."SessionId" = session."Id")
ORDER BY "SessionId"
```

For some reason, I'm getting more then just the common **Title**s.

For example:

**Users**:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Alice |
| 3 | Mike |

**Session**:

| Id | Name | Time | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | s1 | 12PM | 1 |
| 22 | s2 | 12PM | 1 |
| 33 | s3 | 4PM | 2 |

**Consts**:

| Id | Title | Value | SessionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Color | green | 11 |
| 02 | Shape | circle | 11 |
| 03 | Text | Hi | 11 |
| 04 | Color | red | 22 |
| 05 | Text | Go | 22 |
| 06 | Text | Yes | 33 |

The **Title**s that I get are **Color, Shape, Text** and the required ones are **Color, Text**, because these are the common **Title**s of the sessions 11, 22.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected result. Apart from that your query is wrong. It will never produce error.

Comment: Also - what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - I added a sample as you asked. Also - Why my query is wrong?

Comment: @Mureinik - What does it mean?

Comment: @Eli What database product are you using (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc)?

Comment: @Mureinik - Oh.. PostgreSQL

Comment: @Caleb - I read a lot about it, and I still can't solve it..

Comment: What do you mean by common? Where title count > 1?

Comment: I'd expect an error from the above query.